# Legendre Polynomial Integral over half space

Tags: integration, legendre-polynomials

I need to compute the following integral
$$
I_{n,m} := \int_0^1 P_n(x) P_m(x) \; \mathrm{d}x
$$
where $P_n$ is the [Legendre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials).

For an even sum $n+m=2l$ it is easy to show that
$$
I_{n,m} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 P_n(x) P_m(x) \; \mathrm{d}x
= \delta_{n,m} \frac{1}{2n+1} \,.
$$

A length calculation arises for an *odd* sum $n+m=2l+1$. Has someone finished the calculation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integration of Equation (34) in [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html) gives the integral $I_{nm}$ as a sum
$$I_{nm}=\sum _{q=0}^m \frac{2^{-q}}{q+1}  \binom{-m-1}{q} \binom{m}{q} \, _3F_2\left(-n,n+1,q+1;1,q+2;\tfrac{1}{2}\right).$$

As noted by the OP, Mathworld also gives the explicit expression:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The link to MAthWorld was really helpful as there is an easy/explicit solution given there. Look to equation (51,52) or follow those links 
http://oeis.org/A078297
http://oeis.org/A078298

Comment: how could I have missed that! (I added the equations 51,51 for reference)

Answer (score 2):

I found the following answer, based on the idea by

*Dougall, John*, [**The product of two Legendre polynomials**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S2040618500035590), Proc. Glasg. Math. Assoc. 1, 121-125 (1953). [ZBL0052.06404](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0052.06404).

Expand the product in Legendre basis
$$
P_n(x) P_m(x) = \sum_{k=0}^l A_{2k} P_{2l+1-2k}(x)
\\
\quad \text{for} \quad
A_{2k} = \frac{4(l-k)+3}{2(2l-k)+3} 
\frac{\lambda_k \lambda_{n-k} \lambda_{m-k}}{\lambda_{2l+1-k}}
\,, 
\lambda_k = \frac{(2k)!}{2^{n+1} n!}
\,.
$$
Integration is now trivial
$$
I_{n,m} = \sum_{k=0}^l A_{2k} \int_0^1 P_{2l+1-2k}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\\
\int_0^1 P_{2p+1}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{(-1)^p}{4^{p+1}} \frac{(2p)!}{(p!)^2} \frac{2}{p+1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Experimentally, $12(-1)^{k+1}2^{2k}I_{1,2k}$ matches the [super ballot numbers](http://oeis.org/A007054) and $2^{2k+2}I_{k,k+1}$ matches [A018224](http://oeis.org/A018224).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback but this does not answer my question. I asked for general solutions.